# Is there any tool which can show data dependencies within a function

Tags: c++, c

I have this kind of code. What I'm interested in is to find the data dependencies between the loops, so that I can guess If I can run the loops in parallel. Is there any tool which can help me with this.

```
void some_func()
{
 for( ... )
 {
  ...
 }
 for( ... )
 {
  ...
 }
 for( ... )
 {
  ...
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See  [for data flow results computed](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/FlowAnalyzers.html) by our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) and its [C Front End](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CFrontEnd.html).
(Our C++ front won't quite do this yet).

Probably an expensive way to see those dependencies if you only want do to this for one or two loops.  You obviously can do this by hand, and yes it is painful.

Answer (score 0):

You could check this experimental tool [ParTools](https://sourceforge.net/projects/partools/) which shows in a graphical environment the data dependencies in a C program. It allows the interactive analysis of a C program execution profile and data dependencies to facilitate the discovery and selection of suitable parallelization candidates in a manual parallelization process. The flow does not assume any specific parallelization technique, thus it can be broadly applied.

Answer (score -1):

I have not tried this out yet but [`bp`](http://blitzprog.org/features) may be of some help. From the documentation:

> Developing concurrent, parallelly and correctly running software
>   usually requires a lot of knowledge and attention when designing
>   these. bp [automatically tries to parallelize](http://blitzprog.org/articles/automatic-parallelism-data-dependency) some parts of your
>   program and if the compiler thinks it's worth doing so it will replace
>   the sequential code with a multithreaded one.